# Thevenin Theorem Question

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current-source, thevenin

[image]

I am supposed to find the Thevenin equivalent of the above circuit. My method was to take the 33 ohm and 10 ohm resistors in series and turn that into a 43 ohm resistor. I then turned the 43 ohm resistor and the 15 ohm resistor into the parallel equivalent, which is exactly 645/58 ohms. I was left with a 20/15 A source in parallel with a 645/58 ohm resistor and a 12 ohm resistor which is in series with a 2 A source. From there, I used source transformation to turn the 20/15 A source into a 430/29 V source, in series with the same 645/58 ohm resistor. The 645/58 ohm resistor is then in series with the 12 ohm resistor, making a 1341/58 ohm resistor. I then turned the voltage source back into a current source, which was in parallel with the 2 A source. I added together these sources together, then turned it back into a voltage source by multiplying the new current source with the 1341/58 ohm resistor and eventually got a Thevenin voltage rounded to 60.1V. The answer is 28.44 V.

I have checked my working multiple times and cannot find the issue. Can someone please tell me what was wrong with my method. Thank you in advance.

This is what the answers did:

[image]

Comment: If the question is asking for the thevenin equivalent between terminals A and B, then your first step of adding 33+10ohms is already wrong.

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Comment: If you combine them you no longer have access to point B.

Comment: @GodJihyo Sorry, I don't understand why you wont have access to point B, can you please explain why. I'll post what the answers did, because they added them too.

Comment: @Jason2134 Point B is the connection between two resistors, if you combine them into one then point B is somewhere inside that resistor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. My comment was short-sighted. You were actually right in your answer, your teacher is wrong. See my answer for details.

Comment: @ErnestoG The voltage of 28.44V is correct, the resistance of 11.12 ohms is wrong. It should be 33 || 25, not 43 || 15, To three decimal places Vth = 28.448, Rth = 14.224.

Comment: @GodJihyo No, it is not. Disregarding the terminals, you can add 10+33 and they'll be effectively in parallel with the 15 ohms. The current he gets is exactly the sum of the current I get using my superposition approach. I'm happy to be corrected otherwise, but please show proof. But as I see it, 33 cannot be in parallel with 25 because it has the 10 ohms in the middle.

Comment: @ErnestoG See the simulation results I added to my answer, this shows that 35 || 25 gives the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually right in your answer. My first comment was about you not having access to terminal B, but it seems that you accounted for it towards the end of your process (Sorry, but I'm not going to decipher exactly what you did from your text).

Here's the path I would have taken to arrive at the same answer. It appears that your teacher made a mistake in step 3) by writing the current divider formula wrong. If you write it with 43 ohms on the numerator, then you get 60V at the end, but this is wrong.

1. Apply source transformation on the left-most current source and its 15-ohm resistor in parallel -> it'll become a 20V voltage source with a 15 ohm resistor in series.
2. Apply superposition (find this the easiest): find the voltage drop across the load with respect to the 20V source found in 1). You'll see that the 12-ohm resistor can disregarded because the 2A current source is open. Then, the current through the load is also the current flowing through  the 15 and 10 ohm resistor; i.e.:

$$ I_{20V} = \frac{20V}{15\Omega + 33\Omega + 10\Omega} = 0.345A$$

Multiply this current by 33-ohms load to find out its voltage drop. It equals 11.38V.

3. Now, find the voltage drop across the load due to the 2A current source. We apply superposition again, so the 20V source becomes a short.

You have the following schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvz1aP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We'd like to find out the voltage drop across R4.

To this end, we recognize that R3 also has 2A flowing through it, so we might as well imagine that the 2A current is flowing out R3.

From here, we recognize that there's current division between branches R1 and R4+R2, we can, therefore, write:

$$I_{R4} = 2A \frac{15\Omega}{15\Omega + 33\Omega + 10\Omega} = 0.517A$$

This is, effectively, the current flowing through R4, the 33-ohm load. Multiply to get the voltage and you find 17V. Added to the 11.38V I got earlier you find:

$$ 17V + 11.38V = 28.38V$$

If you write the \$I_{R4}\$ formula with the 33+10ohms on the numerator, then you get 1.48A, which then you'd multiply (erroneously) by 33ohms and you find 48.9V, which added to the 11.38V, equals 60.2V.

Whoever wrote that solution for this problem screwed up.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @ErnestoG ! So if I have a resistor in series with another resistor, with an open circuit in between, am I allowed to or not allowed to add them up in series, and why? Thanks again.

Comment: You're allowed to! It's just that you always have to take into account what the nodes of interest are. So, in this case you can do so for a current calculation, but, obviously, you have to "un-add" them in schematic of you want to compute the voltages across the terminals.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjKtRT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_\text{a}&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_\text{b}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{b}&=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_6
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{b}&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_3-0}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_\text{a}&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3-0}{\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}&=\frac{\text{V}_3-0}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_6
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
 FullSimplify[
  Solve[{Ia == I1 + I2, I0 == Ib + I2, I0 == I4 + I5, I3 == I4 + I5, 
    Ib == I3 + I6, I1 == Ia + I6, I1 == V2/R1, Ib == (V1 - V2)/R2, 
    I3 == (V3 - 0)/R3, I4 == (V2 - V3)/R4, I5 == (V2 - V3)/R5}, {I0, 
    I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> ((Ia + Ib) R1 (R4 + R5))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   I1 -> ((Ia + Ib) (R4 R5 + 
       R3 (R4 + R5)))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   I2 -> -Ib + ((Ia + Ib) R1 (R4 + 
        R5))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   I3 -> ((Ia + Ib) R1 (R4 + R5))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   I4 -> ((Ia + Ib) R1 R5)/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   I5 -> ((Ia + Ib) R1 R4)/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   I6 -> Ib - ((Ia + Ib) R1 (R4 + 
        R5))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   V1 -> Ia R1 + Ib R1 + 
     Ib R2 - ((Ia + Ib) R1^2 (R4 + 
        R5))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   V2 -> ((Ia + Ib) R1 (R4 R5 + 
       R3 (R4 + R5)))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   V3 -> ((Ia + Ib) R1 R3 (R4 + 
       R5))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5)}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\left(\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_\text{b}\right)\text{R}_1\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_5\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\left(\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_\text{b}\right)\text{R}_1}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
  Limit[((Ia + Ib) R1 (R4 R5 + 
       R3 (R4 + R5)))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5) - ((Ia + 
       Ib) R1 R3 (R4 + R5))/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), 
   R5 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=((Ia + Ib) R1 R4)/(R1 + R3 + R4)

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
  Limit[((Ia + Ib) R1 R4)/((R1 + R3) R4 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5), R5 -> 0]]

Out[3]=((Ia + Ib) R1)/(R1 + R3)

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=((R1 + R3) R4)/(R1 + R3 + R4)
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{825}{29}\approx28.4483\space\text{V}\tag7$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=2\space\text{A}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{825}{58}\approx14.2241\space\Omega\tag9$$

Answer (score 0):

For a Thevenin equivalent you want to find the resistance you would see across points A and B with all voltage sources short circuited and current sources open circuited.

Start by redrawing the circuit with those conditions met, then looking at points A and B combine resistances.

Removing the current sources takes the 12\$\Omega\$ resistor out of the circuit and you're left with this progression.

[image]

You can check your results by simulating the circuit. Here I show the original circuit, then that circuit with a 100\$\Omega\$ load. Last I show the Thevenin Equivalent using controlled voltage sources to clone the voltage from points A and B, first with the 15\$\Omega\$ and 10\$\Omega\$ in series and then that in parallel with the 33\$\Omega\$, and second the 33\$\Omega\$ in series with the 10\$\Omega\$ and then that in parallel with the 15\$\Omega\$. You can see from the voltages that the first Thevenin equivalent matches what you see on the original circuit with the same 100\$\Omega\$ load.

[image]